# Changing data frame name in loop

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have a question regarding the R syntax for loop.
I have a loop with a character sequence ("i" is a character value) and I want to put it in the ggplot as a data frame name

```
geom_vline(xintercept = i$beat)
```

The case is more complex because the main plot is based on different data set than geom_vline.
How should I write this bit: i$beat to change data frame name in the loop.

And one more thing - I cannot use the lapply here, so it has to be for loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aes_string`. Something along the lines of

```
ggplot(mydata, ...) +
    geom_vline(mapping = aes_string(xintercept = i$beat))
```